# Qual melhor prática para criar uma tabela de usuários?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um sistema web em PHP, e estou em dúvida sobre qual a melhor forma de criar a tabela que receberá as informações do usuário (Velocidade, organização e etc).

Além do `nome`, `email` e `senha`, preciso armazenar `CPF`, `telefone`, `data nascimento` e `endereço`.

Armazeno todas essas informações em uma única tabela ou crio duas tabelas:

- `USUARIO`, que vai receber o `nome`, `email` e `senha`; e
- `INF-COMPLEMENTARES`, para o `CPF`, `telefone`, `data nascimento` e `endereço`?

Answer (score 0):

Vou resumir isso e anexar alguns materiais de referencia; Bora lá

Em um projeto para estudo e pratica, ter uma tabela para usuarios com suas informaçoes vai agilizar seu desenvolvimento,

```
- USUARIOS
```

Em projetos escalaveis (muito maiores) você vai começar a subdividir issso

```
- USUARIOS
- DETALHES_USUARIOS
- LOCALIZAÇÂO
- Emprendimentos
```

Mas para um inicio leia sobre SQL e a implementação em php

https://medium.com/@alexandre.malavasi/25-dicas-e-boas-pr%C3%A1ticas-de-banco-de-dados-para-desenvolvedores-7a60bfc28f1f

https://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/crud-bootstrap-php-mysql-parte1/

Pesquise por modelagem de banco de dados e sua estruturação.